when i used thymeleaf in our code and replace header code into seprate file then not show header tab
I am learning Spring Boot and using Thymeleaf in my project. When I replace the header code as a separate file in the same folder and use Thymeleaf's replace syntax, the CSS, JS, and Bootstrap code is not displayed on the website. When I try to run it on port 8080, only the HTML code is displayed without the CSS, JS, or Bootstrap.
log output error
2024-05-17T09:44:23.684+05:30  WARN 17192 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] actStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8081-exec-1][home.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "footer :: footer" found in template home.html, line 353, col 6. Please use the complete syntax of fragment expressions instead ("~{footer :: footer}"). The old, unwrapped syntax for fragment expressions will be removed in future versions of Thymeleaf.
this is the syntax i use

directory  image 
header file


the problem is likely to be in header.html - it has to have a fragment defined (e.g. <div th:fragment="header">) see https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html

please post actual code (not only images)

I see that you refer to the CSS file like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-starter.css">

Spring Boot serves what is inside the static folder on the root, so you should use something like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style-starter.css}">

